# QT Json saving many data to file and how to read it

Tags: c++, json, qt

So i tried to save many data to a json file but i was unable to save it without strange data formatting or overwriting previous data

I'm doing to make application to organise work and task, i want to save task to .json file and load them after restarting a programm

```
QJsonObject test2;
    test2.contains("name");
    test2.contains("priority");
    test2.contains("description");
    test2.contains("beginDate");
    test2.contains("endDate");

    test2["name"]= "ZyIL";
    test2["priority"]=21;
    test2["description"]="Ja";
    test2["beginDate"]="21.03.02";
    test2["endDate"]="21.04.03";


    QJsonObject test22;
        test22.contains("name");
        test22.contains("priority");
        test22.contains("description");
        test22.contains("beginDate");
        test22.contains("endDate");

        test22["name"]= "AAAAL";
        test22["priority"]=241;
        test22["description"]="JBBBBBe";
        test22["beginDate"]="21.06.02";
        test22["endDate"]="21.08.03";





    QFile d("d.json");
    d.open(QFile::WriteOnly);
    QJsonDocument test3(test2);
    QJsonDocument test33(test22);
    d.write(test3.toJson());
    d.write(test33.toJson());
    d.close();
```

My previous idea was to make a array of QJsonObject and do something like this

```
   QJsonObject test2[2];
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        test2[i].contains("name");
        test2[i].contains("priority");
        test2[i].contains("description");
        test2[i].contains("beginDate");
        test2[i].contains("endDate");

        test2[i]["name"]= "ZyIL";
        test2[i]["priority"]=21;
        test2[i]["description"]="Ja";
        test2[i]["beginDate"]="21.03.02";
        test2[i]["endDate"]="21.04.03";
    }
```

Then .json file looks like this

```
{
    "beginDate": "21.03.02",
    "description": "Ja",
    "endDate": "21.04.03",
    "name": "ZyIL",
    "priority": 21
}
{
    "beginDate": "21.03.02",
    "description": "Ja",
    "endDate": "21.04.03",
    "name": "ZyIL",
    "priority": 21
}
```

So i dont know what can i make to easly save and load. All i found is to use array, but i couldnt figure out how to save json files properly so i cant even try it

Comment: For supposed security reasons JSON is not intended to open files on its own.    The data from your file can be loaded into a string using the "read from text file function".  This function opens files as read-only. If you wire the 'refnum out' output of this function to the file input of a write function, LabVIEW returns a permissions error. Use the Open/Create/Replace File function to open the file with the default read/write access and wire the refnum to the read and write functions. look here : http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361K-01/glang/read_characters_from_file/

Comment: Use `QJsonArray` to create an array of json objects. Then you can use `QJsonDocument` to convert the array from and to a `QByteArray`, which you can then write (and later read) via `QFile` to a file of your choice.

Comment: Felix i cant quite understand how to make this

Dr t- i'm opening the file with  QFile::WriteOnly  so that's not the problem i think